# Sort function to sort my-class

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class Student
{
private:
    int age;
    string name;
public:
    Student(){ }
    ~Student() { }
    friend istream & operator >> (istream& in, Student & a);
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream& out, const Student & a);
    bool operator > (Student& a)
    {
        if (age != a.age)
            return age > a.age;
        else
            return name > a.name;
    }
};
istream & operator >> (istream& in, Student & a)
{
    in >> a.name >> a.age;
    return in;
}
ostream & operator << (ostream& out, const Student & a)
{
    out << a.name << " " << a.age;
    return out;
}
bool cmp( Student *a,Student *b)
{
    return (*a) > (*b);
}
int main()
{
    Student stu;
    vector<Student> students;
    while (cin >> stu) {
        students.push_back(stu);
    }
    sort(students.begin(), students.end(), cmp);
    return 0;
}
```

I defined a class.But when i used sort function to sort it ,it went wrong like

```
No viable conversion from 'Student' to 'Student *'
```

I do not understand,please help me.

Comment: `<algorithm>` uses `operator <` not `operator >`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix that error, you should change the signature of `cmp` from

```
bool cmp( Student *a,Student *b)
{
    return (*a) > (*b);
}
```

to

```
bool cmp(Student const& a, Student const& b)
{
    return a < b;  // Note std::sort uses operator< for comparison
}
```

However, if you simply define `operator<` for `Student`, you do not need this function at all, you can simply call

```
std::sort(students.begin(), students.end());
```

Comment: @Arookile Are you still using `cmp` function?

Comment: @Arookile If it gives you exactly the same error after modification, then you didn't modify it

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Comment: @Arookile Not sure what you need help with, your code in pastie you provided is fully working.

Comment: You've swapped the sort order in cmp here. The simplest fix is `bool cmp(Student const& a, Student const& b){ return b < a; }`

Answer (score 1):

`<algorithm>` uses `operator <` not `operator >`.
so your class become (`const` fixed):

```
class Student
{
private:
    int age;
    string name;
public:
    Student(){}
    ~Student() {}
    friend istream & operator >> (istream& in, Student & a);
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream& out, const Student & a);
    bool operator < (const Student& rhs) const
    {
        return std::tie(age, name) < std::tie(rhs.age, rhs.name);
    }
};
```

Predicate should have signature "compatible" with `bool cmp(const Student&, const Student&)`, your `cmp` function doesn't match.

To sort in descending order, you just have to do:

```
std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), std::greater<>{});
```

For ascending order:

```
std::sort(students.begin(), students.end());
```